# ag-grid: column pinning not working

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying to pin a couple of column groups on the right of a table, but the horizontal scrollbar still works on all the columns.

Here is the columns definition:

```
    this.cols = [{
    headerName : "Security Info",
    marryChildren : true,
    children : [        
        //columns
    ]},
    {
    headerName : "Best",
    marryChildren : true,
    pinned: 'right',
    children : [ 
        //columns
    ]
}, {
    headerName : "My Order",
    marryChildren : true,
    pinned:'right',
    children : [ 
        //columns 
        ]
} ];;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pin the columns themselves, not "parent" columns as you have here.

Pin all the child columns under a group you want pinned and it should work as expected.

Comment: May I suggest this feature on github?

Comment: The problem here is that you can break columns from their parent (if you dont have marryChildren). I'll take it to the team and we can discuss - thanks for the feedback